# How to do conditional statement inside of a Open Cursor in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure on my SQL server which runs every night. The purpose is to calculate the difference between two dates and put the remainder into a column.

I have the following field:s due date, today's date, progress, and remaining days. I calculate the difference between today's date and the due date and store the difference in the remaining days column.

But now I want to check the value of the Progress column, and if the Progress is 'Complete' then I want to skip that remaining days update.

That way, if the job is complete, the remaining days will not continue to count down as the difference becomes further away from today's date.

Here is what I have so far. This works for everything except the conditional check on the progress column. I don't know how to do that inside of the cursor that I am using.

```
DECLARE @due_date DATE 
DECLARE @difference varchar(50) 
DECLARE @id INT

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT [Engr Due] FROM dbo.Employee_Table 

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @due_date 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 
    SELECT @difference = DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), @due_date) 
    UPDATE Employee_Table
        SET [Remaining Days]=@difference 
        WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @due_date 
END

CLOSE myCursor 
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor at all? This entire thing looks like it could be replaced with `update Employee_Table set [Remaining Days] = DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), [Engr Due])`.

Comment: As for the `Progress` thing, do you just want to skip updating rows with a `Progress` value of `Complete`? If so, just add `where Progress <> 'Complete'` to the above.

Comment: Blorgbeard, you are correct, the reason I chose to use a cursor is because I'm new to stored procedures like this so in my attempt to google "how to iterate through a sql table and set values" most results pointed to a cursor. So I just stuck with it, but you have a valid point.

Comment: OK, but you should avoid cursors for performance reasons. If you're processing a lot of records, you might wish to convert it back to a set-based query. In general, iterating through tables is the wrong approach for SQL. It's intended to operate over sets of data - you leave the actual mechanics of iterating to the SQL engine.

Comment: And note that there's no reason you can't put a simple `update` statement in a stored procedure. The fact that it's a sproc doesn't really change anything.

Comment: I changed it to be a simple update statement. For some reason I just never thought it would work like that. Thanks for helping me learn today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep with the cursor, please consider this as a start:

```
DECLARE @due_date DATE, @difference varchar(50), @id INT, @Now datetime = (Select GetDate());

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT [Engr Due], [Progress] 
    FROM dbo.Employee_Table OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @due_date, @Progress
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    if (@Progress != 'Completed')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @difference = DATEDIFF(day, @Now, @due_date) 
        UPDATE Employee_Table
        SET [Remaining Days]=@difference 
        WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor 
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @due_date, @Progress

END

CLOSE myCursor DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Only thing missing was the declaration of @Progress, but that was easy to fix. I learned that you can write multiple values into the cursor like that. Seems simple enough that I should have known. Thank you, this is great.